# Video export incorrect video's length in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, video

I Have created Video successfully from array of images with frame time duration = 1 second for all images. but I want to use different duration time for each of images, exp : 0.1s, 0.2s But It's not work correctly.

```
                while (!self.selectedPhotosArray.isEmpty) {
                if (videoWriterInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData) {
                    let nextDicData = self.selectedPhotosArray.remove(at: 0)
                    if let nextImage = nextDicData["img"] as? UIImage
                    {
                        var frameDuration = CMTimeMake(Int64(0 * 10000), fps)
                        if let timeVl = nextDicData["time"] as? Float{
                               framePerSecond = Int64(timeVl * 10000)

                        }

                        frameDuration =  CMTimeMake(framePerSecond ,fps)

                        let lastFrameTime = CMTimeMake(Int64(lastTimeVl), fps)
                        let presentationTime = frameCount == 0 ? lastFrameTime : CMTimeAdd(lastFrameTime, frameDuration)
                        var pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer? = nil
                        let status: CVReturn = CVPixelBufferPoolCreatePixelBuffer(kCFAllocatorDefault, pixelBufferAdaptor.pixelBufferPool!, &pixelBuffer)
                        if let pixelBuffer = pixelBuffer, status == 0 {
                            let managedPixelBuffer = pixelBuffer
                            CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(managedPixelBuffer, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: CVOptionFlags(0)))
                            let data = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(managedPixelBuffer)
                            let rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
                            let context = CGContext(data: data, width: Int(self.outputSize.width), height: Int(self.outputSize.height), bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(managedPixelBuffer), space: rgbColorSpace, bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedFirst.rawValue)
                            context!.clear(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: CGFloat(self.outputSize.width), height: CGFloat(self.outputSize.height)))
                            let horizontalRatio = CGFloat(self.outputSize.width) / nextImage.size.width
                            let verticalRatio = CGFloat(self.outputSize.height) / nextImage.size.height
                            //let aspectRatio = max(horizontalRatio, verticalRatio) // ScaleAspectFill
                            let aspectRatio = min(horizontalRatio, verticalRatio) // ScaleAspectFit
                            let newSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: nextImage.size.width, height: nextImage.size.height)
                            let x = newSize.width < self.outputSize.width ? (self.outputSize.width - newSize.width) / 2 : 0
                            let y = newSize.height < self.outputSize.height ? (self.outputSize.height - newSize.height) / 2 : 0

                            context?.draw(nextImage.cgImage!, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height))
                            CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(managedPixelBuffer, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: CVOptionFlags(0)))
                            appendSucceeded = pixelBufferAdaptor.append(pixelBuffer, withPresentationTime: presentationTime)
                        } else {
                            print("Failed to allocate pixel buffer")
                            appendSucceeded = false
                        }
                    }

                }
                if !appendSucceeded {
                    break
                }
                frameCount += 1
               lastTimeVl += framePerSecond

            }
```

Comment: Could you share some more info about what you've tried, docs that might point in the right direction, errors you are running into, etc? It's hard to know what specifically you are struggling with in a big block of code. Is this code from your 1 second example? Do you have an attempt at the changes you are trying to make that you could share along with why it's not working for you?

Comment: that code do change duration of each image . it's export video with incorrect length, example: i have 4 images with each duration are : 0.1s , 0.2s, 1s , 0.5s but its exported to 4 hours video's length